# this.state.persons.map is not a function but persons is already an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It's my first time working with React and I'm having some trouble with starting to use Axios. I watched a video, a very simple practical tutorial that showed how to use a get function, but I think something went wrong because even following the same exact steps I still get the error "this.state.persons.map is not a function". I want to stress the fact that the author of the video uses this exact same JavaScript code, and for him it works. Any explanation?

Here's the whole code for reference:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class personList extends React.Component{
    state = {
        persons: [],
    };

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com`)
        .then(res =>{
            console.log(res);
            this.setState({persons: res.data});
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.persons.map(person => <li key={person.id}>{person.name}</li>)}
            </ul>
            )
    }
}
```

I looked around for an answer, but every other case that has been presented is either too different (using set arrays, json and whatnot) or it refers to a string used instead of an array, which causes the error, and obviously it's not my case.

Comment: What does your `console.log` of `res` show it containing?

Comment: That url goes to their main html page, not to the paths that return json

Comment: When you request https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ you got full page.
You should console.log to see what is inside, map is function which have to be implemented on array type of data.

You should add /users in your api (like this https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a GET request at `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` which returns the whole webpage. If you want to fetch the users, use this URL instead: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`

Comment: Aaaand! It turns out I DIDN'T copy the code perfectly! Thanks, now it works!

Comment: Happy to help. :D